# C++ inheritance - virtual function that takes in pointer to this class as parameter

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Say I have an object `Node`, which has a function `addPath()` that expects another `Node` as an argument.

```
virtual void Node::addPath(Node * otherNode)
{
     // does something with otherNode
}
```

Now, say I derive from `Node`. Let's call this `DerivedNode`, and it has a new function `foo()`. I want to override the `addPath` method. I also know when I call `DerivedNode::addPath`, the parameter would always be another `DerivedNode`. Meaning I want to be able to call `foo()` inside the `addPath()` method.

```
int DerivedNode::foo(); 

void DerivedNode::addPath(Node * otherNode)
{
     int x = foo();   // no problem
     int y = otherNode->foo()   // BAD! otherNode is typed as Node, not DerivedNode
}
```

I can't call `otherNode->foo()`. What should I do?

Obviously I know I can cast, but that seems like a clunky rookie solution. Do we have anything more elegant? I feel like this should be a fairly common use case.

Comment: what's wrong with overriding `addPath()` as you said?

Comment: Casting is the only way, sorry. `dynamic_cast` is safest.

Comment: Sounds like a case for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but then you need to loose the virtual ...

Comment: Welcome to the new wonderful world of *binary methods* (google this). Please put your problem aside for a while and do an exercise. Define an abstract class Number from which Integer, Real, Complex and others all derive. How would you define addition for the abstract class?

Comment: I think the actual code in `AddPath` matters here. If you really know it will always need to be a `DerivedNode` to correctly function then take that as a parameter. If it may not always be a `DerivedNode` then clearly state in the question what should happen for instances that don't provide a `foo` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

you have to cast, unless you set something like this in your base class. but all derived classes need to implement it, depends on your program.

```
virtual int foo() = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call 'foo' method because is not a member of base Node. Indeed you could to a cast but make sure that type of node argument is indeed a DerivedNode otherwise your will get an exception.
Yes, you could call  x = foo() method from addPath method because you are making calls from DerivedNode class.

Or you could define foo() as virtual method in your base class. Either make it abstract but in this case you will not be able to create an Node instance or you could provide a default/empty implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your Node class is an abstract class for 2 types of nodes:

- you're gonna have your leaf nodes, that perform some functionality
- you're gonna have your composite nodes, that will store other nodes

In this context, 2 questions arise:

1. Why does the base class have the 'addNode' method? Leaf nodes won't have any use for it...
2. What does foo() do? Perhaps adding 'addNode' to the base class, and then making 'foo()' into a *template method* would be a good approach.

Once you answer those, you will get a clearer picture of the responsibilities those methods hold - and that in turn will give you a hint **where** (in which class) to put them.

Answer (score -1):

If only one of your derived classes needs a foo() operation, then you should use a dynamic cast (or reconsider your design).

If the "foo" operation is one that applies to more than one derived class, then you should add a virtual method foo() to your base class(Node).

- If (almost) every derived class needs some type of foo operation, then make the foo() method abstract (pure.)
- If many of the derived classes don't need a foo() operation then make it be a "no-operation" in the base class so derived classes that do NOT need to foo() can simply ignore the issue.

The code below uses this technique.

```
class Node
{
    virtual void Node::addPath(Node * otherNode)
    {
         // does something with otherNode
    }
    virtual void foo()
    {
        // nothing to do in the base class
    }
};

class DerivedNode : public Node
{
    void DerivedNode::addPath(Node * otherNode)
    {
        int x = foo();   // no problem
        int y = otherNode->foo(); // Now this works.
    }
    void foo()
    {
        // this is the DervivedNode-specific foo!
        Node::foo(); // just in case the base class has an opinion
        do my foo-ish stuff here;
    }
};
```

Comment: "can simply ignore the issue" until it bites you

Comment: @n.m. If ignoring it will bite you, then make it pure so it can't be ignored.

Comment: Making it pure in the base classis pretty much a given. How you *define* it in your *concrete* classes id it doesn't make sense for them? "Ignoring the issue" is defining it as a no-op.

Comment: I guess you've never encountered the case where "making it a no-op" is exactly the right solution.  I've used this approach for 30 years and gosh, it works just fine every single time I use it!

Comment: Of course it *can* be the right solution, but it can also bring in unwanted dependencies, ugly workarounds and what not.

Comment: Which is why those words up there that I wrote suggest that either pure virtual or default virtual implement in base class is works depending on the situation.  I expect a reasonable degree of intelligence and competent from anyone claiming to be a programmer.

Comment: Neither of your suggestions works well, that's the problem with them.